# React changes the state only if button is clicked twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a beginner with react and when I'm using useState to change name of the button, it does not work as intended.
Specifically: when I'm pushing the button it's name "Unclicked" must change to "Clicked" and when I push it again it should change back to "Unclicked" and so on. In reality, when I click the button it changes to "Clicked" in one click but to change it back, the button must be pushed twice.

[image: My code]

[image: the result]

Well, I'm expecting the button to change it's name on only one click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrongly using `clicked` variable. it will be reset to 0 every time component re-renders.

change to

```
if(buttonName === 'Unclicked')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code as following!

```
const Test = () => {
const [buttonName, setButtonName] = useState("Unclicked");

return (
    <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <Button onClick={() => {buttonName == "Unclicked" ? setButtonName("Clicked") : setButtonName("Unclicked")}} variant="contained">
            {buttonName}
        </Button>
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).